# How to round json response in meter test?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

When I run JMeter tests I get this response in JMeter:

[image]

I am using JSR223 to check the value I get this way:

[image]

But the assertion returns this:

[image]

Can you help me rounding this number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please [edit] your question and replace the images with actual text?  You can indent your code with 4 spaces before the code lines so it formats as code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
vars.put("appc", response.APPC.toString());
```

to this one:

```
vars.put("appc", response.APPC.round(9).toString());
```

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Round and Truncate Decimal Values](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-round-and-truncate.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)